# PHP Mobile_Detect -- Function for isPhone()

Tags: php, mobile

I've recently downloaded PHP's Mobile_Detect Class, and want to be able to detect if someone is browsing from a mobile phone.

From what I've seen, there are two functions `isMobile()` and `isTablet()` -- `isMobile()` determines if they're browsing from a phone or a tablet, and `isTablet()` checks if they're browsing from a tablet.

As far as I can tell there is no function like `isPhone()` that will detect if they're browsing from a mobile phone.

If anyone has experienced the same issue, I'd love to hear how you resolved it.

Thank you

Comment: How about `isMobile() && !isTablet()`?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that, but yes, that's a great solution. Thanks so much

Comment: I revolutionize the game on the daily. Nbd.

Comment: Here's what the demo code uses: `$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');`